# PHP replace array index key with values from other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have these 2 arrays and I need to replace the numeric indices of $products with the indices of $columns.

I don't know if it is correct to solve it with "foreach loop" or with another PHP function.

PROBLEM: the returned array must have the same number of elements as the initial one.

```
$columnas = array( "CATEGORIA", "PRODUCTO", "IMAGEN", "PRECIO", "DESCUENTO", "DISPONIBLE");
$products = array(
    array(
        "Burgers", "Doble con queso", "burger.jpg","300"
    ),
    array(
        "Burgers", "Triple", "burger_triple.jpg", "350", "10%", "si"
    ),
    array(
        "Burgers", "Triple2", "burger_triple.jpg", "380"
    ),
    array( "Burgers", "Triple3"
    ),
);
```

In the loop I go through both arrays to replace the indexes.

```
foreach( $products as $k => $product  ) {
    foreach($product as $t => $y){
        $columnsArray[$columnas[$t]] = $y;
        // $product[$columnas[$t]] = $y; // Other option
    }
    $newProducts[] = $columnsArray;
}
print_r($newProducts);
```

This is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Doble con queso
            [IMAGEN] => burger.jpg
            [PRECIO] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Triple
            [IMAGEN] => burger_triple.jpg
            [PRECIO] => 350
            [DESCUENTO] => 10%
            [DISPONIBLE] => si
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Triple2
            [IMAGEN] => burger_triple.jpg
            [PRECIO] => 380
            [DESCUENTO] => 10% <------- should not be
            [DISPONIBLE] => si <------- should not be
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Triple3
            [IMAGEN] => burger_triple.jpg <------- should not be
            [PRECIO] => 380 <------- should not be
            [DESCUENTO] => 10% <------- should not be
            [DISPONIBLE] => si <------- should not be
        )

)
```

Comment: So what is your exact desired result?  Please [edit] your question to form a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$columnas = array( "CATEGORIA", "PRODUCTO", "IMAGEN", "PRECIO", "DESCUENTO", "DISPONIBLE");
$products = array(
    array(
        "Burgers", "Doble con queso", "burger.jpg","300"
    ),
    array(
        "Burgers", "Triple", "burger_triple.jpg", "350", "10%", "si"
    ),
    array(
        "Burgers", "Triple2", "burger_triple.jpg", "380"
    ),
    array( "Burgers", "Triple3"
    ),
);
$newProducts = [];
foreach ($products as $p) {
        // slice out the same number of keys from $columnas, combine into the new array
        $newProducts[] = array_combine(array_slice($columnas,0,count($p)),$p);
}
print_r($newProducts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this is what you're after

```
$data = [];
foreach ($products as $k => $product) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($columnas as $i => $key) {
        $result[$key] = (isset($product[$i]) ? $product[$i] : null);
    }
    $data[] = $result;
}

print_r($data);
```

The problem with your version was that you weren't creating a clean array inside the loop, so missing values would remain from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You should start each iteration of the nested foreach with an empty `$columnsArray`

**Note** that you are looping a products array, and using those numerical keys to directly index into the `$columnas` array.

This can cause an undefined array key if there are more products than columns.

```
foreach( $products as $k => $product  ) {
    $columnsArray = [];
    foreach($product as $t => $y){
        if (array_key_exists($t, $columnas)) {
            $columnsArray[$columnas[$t]] = $y;
        }
    }
    $newProducts[] = $columnsArray;
}
print_r($newProducts);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Doble con queso
            [IMAGEN] => burger.jpg
            [PRECIO] => 300
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Triple
            [IMAGEN] => burger_triple.jpg
            [PRECIO] => 350
            [DESCUENTO] => 10%
            [DISPONIBLE] => si
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Triple2
            [IMAGEN] => burger_triple.jpg
            [PRECIO] => 380
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CATEGORIA] => Burgers
            [PRODUCTO] => Triple3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_reduce($products, function($accumulator, $item) use ($columnas){
if(count($item) < count($columnas)){
    $item = array_pad($item, count($columnas),NULL);
}
$accumulator[] = array_combine($columnas,$item);
return $accumulator;
},[]);
print_r($result);
```

You can see outputs and test this [here](https://replit.com/@YusifAghayev/StudiousElectricParser#main.php)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without nested loops or if-statements.

```php
$products = array_map(function (array $product) use ($columns): array {
    $product = array_pad($product, count($columns), null);

    return array_combine($columns, $product);
}, $products);
```

Or, if you'd rather have the missing keys omitted rather than carry a null placeholder:

```php
$products = array_map(function (array $product) use ($columns): array {
    $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, count($product));

    return array_combine($columns, $product);
}, $products);
```